# router.put not displaying correct errorMessage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, react-router, mern

Working with a router.put that is failing to show the correct error message.

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
try{
    const {title, description, code} = req.body;
    const snippetId = req.params.id;
    
    // validation

    if(!description && !code){
        return res.status(400).json({errorMessage: "You need to enter at least a description or some code"});
    }

    if(!snippetId){
        return res.status(400).json({errorMessage: "Snippet ID not given. Please contact the developer."});
    }

    const originalSnippet = await Snippet.findById(snippetId);

    // this is the error message I need to display
    if(!originalSnippet){
        return res.status(400).json({errorMessage: "No snippet with this ID was found. Please contact the developer."});
    }

    originalSnippet.title = title;
    originalSnippet.description = description;
    originalSnippet.code = code;

    const savedSnippet = await originalSnippet.save();

    res.json(savedSnippet);
}
catch(err){
    res.status(500).send();
}
});
```

Using insomnia, when attempting to update a snippetId that doesn't exist, I should get the error message above to display, but instead I get the following:

```
No body returned for response
```

I am getting no code related errors.  I just want the error message in question to be displayed.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The `catch` block most likely gets triggered, inside which you return no body, just the 500 http code. Have you tried doing `console.log(err)` inside your `catch` block to see the error?

Comment: @codemonkey - You are a genius.  Adding the console.log in the catch gave me an error that read "reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters".  That led me to believe that the Id that I was testing was too long.   When I entered a shorter Id that does not exist, the appropriate error message was displayed.  Thank you for helping a dude out.